# Moving 2 cells down simultaneously in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

Moving multiple cells down rows in a loop

I'm very new to VBA and I'm trying to teach myself. I have 4 columns that I'm working with. "I" is a starting date, "J" is an ending date, "M" is daily spend, and "N" is weekly spend.

I have it right now to say if the current date is greater than the start date and less than the end date, multiply "M" by 7. It works for one row. The problem is I can't get all columns to go down. Meaning, start date is the active cell and that I can get to offset. I can't get the daily to offset row as well. I've tried everything I know how to do and looked at a lot of different forums but can't make it work. I'm sure this is very basic but any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub WeeklyAdvertisingSpend()

Dim dspend As Currency
Dim wspend As Currency


dspend = Worksheets("2018 Information").Range("m3")

wspend = dspend * 7

Range("i3").Activate

Do Until ActiveCell = Empty
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate


        If Range("i3") <= Date And Range("j3") >= Date Then

        Range("n3").Value = wspend

        End If



Loop



End Sub
```

Use the if then statement to find weekly spend of different advertising campaigns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like so, without OFFSETs, but using a row counter. The loop starts at row 3 and ends at the last used entry in column I (row `n`).

```
Sub WeeklyAdvertisingSpend()

Dim dspend As Currency
Dim wspend As Currency
Dim n As Long, r As Long

With Worksheets("2018 Information")
    n = .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 3 To n
        If .Cells(r, "I") <= Date And .Cells(r, "J") >= Date Then
            .Cells(r, "N") = .Cells(r, "M") * 7
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```